# How to typeset a reference to a footnote?

Tags: formatting, footnotes

I want to enter in a footnote a reference to another footnote (in this case it's on the same page above).

I found out how I can create the reference, so that it is formatted like a "normal" footnote number ([How can I use \footnotemark with a \ref argument?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16866/how-can-i-use-footnotemark-with-a-ref-argument)), but **how should I typeset it?**

Is it ok like in the picture below (in english "see footnote" with a `space`between the word "footnote" and the footnotemark?

Or how could that be done better?

- Maybe without the space?
- .. or even not as a footnotemark, but as a normal number (in normalsize)?

[image: example]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my opinion, you should use full-size numbers -- not only for references to footnotes, but also for the actual notes.

Quoting Bringhurst, *The Elements of Typographic Style*, p. 69:

> *4.3.3 Use superscripts in the text but full-size numbers in the notes
>   themselves*
>
> In the main text, superscript numbers
>   are used to indicate notes because
>   superscript numbers minimize
>   interruption. They are typographic
>   asides: small because that is an
>   expression of their relative
>   importance, and raised for two reasons:
>   to keep them out of the flow of the
>   main text, and to make them easier to
>   find. In the note itself, the number
>   is not an aside but a target.
>   Therefore the number in the note
>   should be full size.

EDIT: Here's an example using the scrextend package which is part of KOMA-script:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{scrextend}
\deffootnote{2em}{1.6em}{\thefootnotemark\hspace{0.7em}}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext\footnote{\blindtext}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks, that sounds convincing. Does this also correspond to German  typographic conventions? BTW, I'd propose to use the KOMA-script class `scrartcl` in the example

Comment: @Martin: I use KOMA-script classes, too -- I just wanted to point out that one may also use `\deffootnote` with the standard classes. As for German typographic conventions: Some are good, some are bad, and some (e.g. for footnotes) may be non-existent.

Comment: a comment _en passant_: this convention about footnotes is enforced in the French rules for typography, as is seen when one employs `\usepackage[french]{babel}`

Answer (score 5):

Use the `\deffootnote` command as was given by Lockstep to change the footnote display. Regarding your question about the reference to a different footnote inside a footnote you can use the following `\reffnmark` command. Note that the * version gives the original mark and can be also be used to point intext footnotes to the same footnote (repeated footnote). I prefer the normal  sized number to refere to a footnote, e.g. footnote (10).

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\reffnmark{%
    \@ifstar{\@reffnmarks}{\@reffnmark}}
\newcommand{\@reffnmarks}[1]{%
    \begingroup
        \unrestored@protected@xdef\@thefnmark{\ref{#1}}%
    \endgroup
    \@footnotemark}
\newcommand{\@reffnmark}[1]{(\ref{#1})}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

This is a footnote test\footnote{first footnote\label{fn:first}}\par
Footnote\reffnmark*{fn:first} pointing to same footnote\par
Footnote\footnote{In footnote \reffnmark{fn:first} ...} with ref to first\par

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great solution! Is it possible to get a reference with the normal sized, non-superscript number /without/ parentheses?

Comment: @Mårten: Yes, just rewrite the command `\newcommand{\@reffnmark}[1]{\ref{#1}}` by removing the parentheses.