# Is there any difference between nesting \label in \caption and putting \label outside \caption?

Tags: cross-referencing, captions, nesting

Is there any difference in behavior between the following coding styles?

### Coding style A: `\caption` does not enclose `\label`.

```
\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics{cat.eps}      
  \caption{This is a cat.}
  \label{fig:cat}
\end{figure}
```

### Coding style B: `\caption` encloses `\label`.

```
\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics{cat.eps}      
  \caption{\label{fig:cat}This is a cat.}      
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Does B not put the label also in the List of Figures?

Comment: I'm not sure about how LaTeX views the differences technically, but from a syntax or logical view one is labeling a figure, and one is labeling a figure caption. Presumably style A makes more sense.

Comment: This is relevant when using R-markdown (.Rmd) to generate pdf files with latex. The result of ![Figure caption \label{fig:1}](image.png) is variant A. Thank you for asking this so we figured out that this is trivial.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I can't say for sure with ordinary LaTeX, but if you use the [`showlabels`](http://ctan.org/pkg/showlabels) package (very useful when in draft mode) then the label is shown in a different place for the two.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{showlabels}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics{vignettes}      
  \caption{This is a cat.}
  \label{fig:cat}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics{vignettes}      
  \caption{\label{fig:cat}This is a cat.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: labels and showlabels]

Comment: Interesting. Style A makes sens for readability of drafts with showlables then.

Answer (score 6):

There are no differences from a Latex internal command view. For example the command `\addtocontents` is defined as

```
\long\def\addtocontents#1#2{%
    \protected@write\@auxout
        {\let\label\@gobble \let\index\@gobble \let\glossary\@gobble}%
        {\string\@writefile{#1}{#2}}}
```

In other word `\label` is made a no-op when `\caption` or `\section` pass arguments to the TOC and LOF. The same goes for `\markboth`, etc. commands to write section headers to the runnings head.  On the other hand is the `\if@nobreak` switch used internaly at a lot of places to prevent `\label` to cause a page break, for example in the `\@afterheading` command after a section command. It is clear that LaTeX was designed to put labels inside or after the `\caption` and `\sectionxxx` commands.

Note that a label must NOT be put in the short argument of `\caption` or `\section`

```
\caption[\label{xx}Short capt]{Long capt}% DO NOT DO THIS
```

because the label will diseapear.

---

**EXCEPTION:** For footnotes the labels must be inside the footnote itself otherwise it is not defined and will refer to the current active counter, which will probably be a section counter.

Comment: What information can I get when using a footnote reference? Just curious...

Comment: @Christoph:  It is usefull to have multiple footnote marks that refer to the same footnote see my answer in the post [Multiple references to the same footnote ..](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10102/multiple-references-to-the-same-footnote-with-hyperref-support-is-there-a-bette). The answer that were marked correct was not the best one :-(  In the documentation of the [`refstyle`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/refstyle) package I give examples of this inside tables

Comment: IIRC Lamport suggests putting `\label` inside `\caption`.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know there are only two differences between coding style A and B:

1. A is the conventional order of the figure environment.
2. A is easier to read.

Comment: (2) is less objective. :-)

Comment: I think it is quite objective. It is easier to read just like the label produced by style A is easier to read in [the answer of @Andrew Stacey](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20816/is-there-any-difference-between-nesting-label-in-caption-and-putting-label-out/20824#20824).

Comment: I you leave your answer as is, it is still less objective.

Answer (score 1):

[How to fix paragraph's run-in heading on a single page before \afterpage and the text being on the first page after \afterpage?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/281928/how-to-fix-paragraphs-run-in-heading-on-a-single-page-before-afterpage-and-the/352237#352237)

The thread above illustrates a case for which the use of coding style B at the top (label within marker being labeled as in `\caption{\label{fig:cat}This is a cat.}`) is necessary to get correct result.  Specifically, in that particular case, coding of `\paragraph{title}\label{text}` leads to bad page breaking in conjunction with the `\afterpage` package, whereas `\paragraph{title\label{text}}` does not.

Also, according to that thread, it is preferred to put the label within the item being tagged.

So it may be that location of label has other ramifications?

Comment: It's better if you make this answer complete, instead of making us go to another thread.  But that thread is dealing with `\paragraph` instead of `\caption`, and it seems that "within or immediately after" is preferred over "sometime later".  That says to me that style A or B is preferred over "put the label a paragraph later" (which would be weird for labeling a figure).

Comment: Ok, let me rephrase this a bit.