# References won't resolve even after repeated compilation

Tags: cross-referencing, captions

I have the following lines:

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\label{fig:sampleconfig}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=1.5cm, grow=down,
    every node/.style={minimum size=1cm,circle,thin,draw},
    edge from parent/.style={-latex, thin, draw}
]
\node {$A$}
    child {
        node {$CO_{1}$}
        child {node[rectangle,draw] {$CL_{1}$}}
    }
    child {
        node[circle,dotted,draw] {$\cdots$}
        child {node[rectangle,dotted,draw] {$\cdots$}}
    }
    child {
        node {$CO_{n}$}
        child {node[rectangle,draw] {$CL_{n}$}}
    }
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Sample configuration}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

In Figure ~\ref{fig:sampleconfig}, the node labelled $A$ is the root APPLICATION node.
```

No matter how many times I recompile the LaTeX file, I still get two question marks in place of "Figure 1," like so:  "Figure ??."

Am I doing something incorrectly?

Thanks in advance for your help.

EDIT

In case it would help to solve the problem:  I'm using MikTex 2.9 on Windows 7.

Comment: The `\label` command *must* go *after* the `\caption` (or inside its argument). Besides you shouldn't be using the `center` environment, but rather the simple command `\centering` in place of `\begin{center}`

Comment: related question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20816/is-there-any-difference-between-nesting-label-in-caption-and-putting-label-ou

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion about \centering.  I've updated my LaTeX file accordingly.

Comment: If your references still do not resolve after correctly placing the `label{}` command, see this related question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/377685/61946

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Put your label in the `caption` itself. i.e.

```
\caption{Sample configuration\label{fig:sampleconfig}}
```

It should work then. You can also place it after the `caption` as long as it is still in the figure environment. Figure labels do not behave correctly if they are placed before the `caption`.

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem persists even after following your suggestion.  I have a feeling it might have something to do with MikTex.  I think if I transfer the LaTex file to my Fedora workstation, download all the TeX packages and compile there, everything will show up correctly.  But someone here must know better than me about this problem.

Comment: It is extremely unlikely that this is a MikTeX problem. Are you sure? Delete the aux file and try a couple more times if you didn't delete it before. You also need to upgrade the example above to a MWE that demonstrates your problem. Inserting your code in a shell article with just the TikZ package included shows your problem until I perform the change detailed in the answer.

Comment: I put the `label` command after the `caption` command and not inside it. It worked for me!