# References do not resolve even after repeated compilation

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, cleveref

If my references do not resolve after repeated compilation, and [I have correctly placed the `\label{}` commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35612/61946), what else should I consider?

Comment: I originally was adding this to the linked question but @Schweinebacke insisted that despite the same overall problem, it deserved a separate question because it was not the same specific issue.

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Also related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/338141/cleveref-with-hyperref-uses-wrong-label-when-referring-to-line-in-code-listing, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53191/impact-of-hyperref-when-varioref-and-cleveref-are-used, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113719/cleveref-fails-to-reference-algorithms, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1863/16923

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek I would not have been able to create a MWE until after solving the issue b/c I did not know where the issue was coming from.

Comment: @Schweinebacke While I realize these linked post (or the one marked as being an exact duplicate) when I searched the problem I had both on StackExchange and Google, none of these came up.  The problem I had was the references did not resolve.  I did not think to check the interaction of hyperref and cleveref.  These other posts only seem useful *after* you know what the problem is.

Comment: The way you arrive at a MWE is by removing everything you think doesn't cause the problem.  At some point you remove something and your problem is fixed, so you know that's part of the MWE.  Eventually, you've removed everything but the 9 lines that show the problem happens, and you've arrived at your MWE.  You also realize that it somehow involves the packages hyperref and cleveref, leading you to google that and get your answer.

Comment: @Teepeemm I understand how to create a MWE.  That is essentially how I solved my problem.  I wanted to provide information to help the next person who is confused why their references are not resolving but they do have the `label` commands in the correct place.  I am not sure if including `hyerref` after `cleveref` is the only way to create this problem.  I created this as a place people could find other things to check for, hopefully saving someone the time of creating a MWE.  To me the other linked questions and answers are only helpful if you know what the problem already is to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you are importing both `hyperref` and `cleveref`. In this case, I found I had to import `cleveref` second in order for the `\cref` references to resolve.  [This blog post introducing `cleveref`](https://texblog.org/2013/05/06/cleveref-a-clever-way-to-reference-in-latex/) has the following warning at the top of the page:

"**Warning: `cleveref`** has to be loaded **after `hyerref`!**"