# Is there a difference between having \label before or after \caption?

Tags: cross-referencing, captions

I am wondering if it is recommended to adhere to a convention of defining labels before or after captions. Moreover, if that is the case, why?

Comment: As far as I know, you should always define the label **after** a caption. If you define it before, it will refer to a previous caption, and the reference in text won't be correct.

Comment: This is discussed in some depth under [Is there any difference between nesting \label in \caption and putting \label outside \caption?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20816/28808).  The question is slightly different but the answer is likely to be similar.

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate, thank you for the swift reply though :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is `\caption` that provides the number information that `\label` stores. If `\label` is placed before `\caption` it catches some irrelevant information.