# What's the difference between "\caption" and "\label" in a "figure" environment?

Tags: floats, cross-referencing, captions

Take this as an example

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[keepaspectratio, width=0.8\linewidth]{transformer_img.pdf}
    \caption{Transformer}
    \label{fig:transformer}
\end{figure}
```

I've searched online but didnt find similar questions? Many questions such as this [Is there any difference between nesting \label in \caption and putting \label outside \caption?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20816/is-there-any-difference-between-nesting-label-in-caption-and-putting-label-ou) did not tell me the differences between them.

I wonder where people learnt the basics of this?

Also, from my vague understanding, after using `\label{fig:transformer}` I can cross-reference the figure anywhere by using `\ref{fig:transformer}`. Is it right? Besides this, where else can `\label` be used for?

Comment: Normally, `\caption` increments the figure counter (`\refstepcounter{figure}`) and writes the caption.  `\label` writes `\@currentlabel` and `\thepage` to the aux file (`\newlabel`).  The caption packaage and hyperref modify the code is several ways.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thank you! this is very complicated for me to understand atm. The only thing I noticed is that the information I input in `\label{}` is not shown anywhere in the output pdf.

Comment: `\label` is like `id=` in html, it makes no output. It is just an internal name for `\ref` to reference

Comment: @DavidCarlisle so what are `\label{}` used for? Im still very confused about this.
PS: Oh thank you I see. So It is only used in `\ref`

Comment: somewhere else in  your document use `see figure \ref{fig:transformer}` and latex will fill in the number. It is like having `<h2 id="foo">a heading</h2>` in html which you link to with `<a href="#foo">xxx</a>`   the text `foo` does not appear in the html

Comment: Take a look at the aux file, which consists of LaTeX code to be implemented dusing `\begin{document}` in the next run.  BTW, `\newlabel{foo}{...}` will create a global macro `\r@foo`.

Comment: As to where people learned this, I read about it in [Lamport's book](https://www.amazon.co.uk/LaTeX-Preparation-Reference-Addison-Wesley-Techniques/dp/0201529831). Others might have read about it in the [Not So Short Guide](https://ctan.org/pkg/lshort), which is free.

Comment: also https://www.learnlatex.org/en/lesson-09  which is available in 9 languages,

Comment: @IanThompson Thank you for the resources!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you for the resources!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some thoughts, deliberately phrased at an introductory to intermediate level.

- For floating environments -- including the `figure` and `table` environments,`\caption` can be used without `\label` but `\label` without `\caption` won't generate the desired result.
- The two floating environments provided by the LaTeX kernel are called `figure` and `table`, respectively. Both of these environments can take one or more `\caption` directives. Some LaTeX packages either provide additional "floating" envionments "out of the box" -- e.g., the `algorithm` package provides the `algorithm` float -- or make it reasonably straightforward for users to create new floating environments from scratch.
- The main cross-referencing mechanism provided by the LaTeX kernel builds on `\label` and `\ref` statements.
- If placed correctly, `\label{<arg>}` creates an association between `<arg>` and the value of the most-recently-incremented LaTeX counter variable. Conversely, `\ref{<arg>}` outputs the value of the counter associated with `<arg>`.
- The condition "if placed correctly" used above means that, for `figure` and `table` floats, the `\label` directive *must come after* the `\caption` directive. Why? Because it's the `\caption` directive that increments the counters called `figure` and `table`, respectively. Incidentally, it is immaterial whether the `\label` directive is placed inside or outside (but after) the argument of the `\caption` directive. (By "outside but after", it is understood that the `\label` directive should placed *before* the current float environment ends. In practice, you can't go wrong if you place `\label` immediately after `\caption`.)
- Several LaTeX packages, including [prettyref](https://ctan.org/pkg/prettyref), [smartref](https://ctan.org/pkg/smartref), [fancyref](https://ctan.org/pkg/fancyref), [hyperref](https://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref), and [cleveref](https://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref), provide additional possibilities for creating cross-references. Some of these packages -- notably, `hyperref` and `cleveref` -- modify the default properties of the basic `\label` directive. For more information about these packages, please see the posting [Cross-reference packages: which to use, which conflict?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36295/5001)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Note that \@currentlabel is set locally, so \label has to be in the same environment or group as the \caption.

Comment: @JohnKormylo - Thanks. Good point. I'll be happy to incorporate your point in my answer. I won't refer to `\@currentlabel` explicitly, though. :-)