# Multiple references to the same footnote inside a table environment

Tags: tables, footnotes

I followed the steps in this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10116/25186) to get multiple references to the same footnotes working. As shown in this minimal example, the solution is working great for footnotes in the text, also getting the correct hyper references in the compiled pdf.

But when using multiple footnotes in a table environment the solution doesn't work, for the second reference in the table environment I get "a^0" instead of another "^a". I guess the problem is that numbering consist of (a,b,...) instead of numbers but I'd like to keep that behavior.

How should I adapt the solution to work inside the table environment ??

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefformat{footnote}{#2\footnotemark[#1]#3}

\begin{document}

This is a paragraph\footnote{\label{first}some footnote}.

This is another paragraph\footnote{\label{second}another footnote}.

This is another paragraph using the first footnote\cref{first}.


\begin{table}
\caption{A table}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{r r r}
\hline
  E\footnote{\label{1sttablefoot}Some table footnote} & F\cref{1sttablefoot} & G \footnote{Another table footnote}  \\  \hline 

  1 & 2 & 3  \\ \hline

\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Can't attach the image result because of being new user :S

Comment: In short: Take a look on the package `savefnmark`, alas in MiKTeX without documentation, see http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/savefnmark/ I don’t know, whether it works with `cleveref`. And defining 5 columns, but using only 3 is odd. See enhanced packages like `array`.

Comment: thanks for your comments, about the 5 columns, that come up wrong because of fast creating the example.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could use [my answer to the same question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/58028/5049) and use `\footref` provided by `scrextend` (part of the [KOMA-Script](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) bundle). This is at least working partially. For reasons I haven't figured out yet the hyperlink from `\footref` inside the table links to the table caption, though, instead of the footnote. I don't know if that is a failure of `scrextend` or `hyperref`…

```
\documentclass{article}
% call `scrextend' before `hyperref'!
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

This is a paragraph\footnote{\label{first}some footnote}.

This is another paragraph\footnote{\label{second}another footnote}.

This is another paragraph using the first footnote\footref{first}.


\begin{table}
\caption{A table}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{rrr}
 \hline
  E\footnote{\label{1sttablefoot}Some table footnote} &
  F\footref{1sttablefoot} &
  G \footnote{Another table footnote} \\
 \hline 
  1 & 2 & 3 \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! this solution is working great, i missed this one in the other question. I don't mind about the linking to the caption, since the table and its foots are always on the same page in my case, there is no problem at all.

Comment: I am currently trying to deploy this nice solution to my document ([journal]{IEEEtran}), however, the latex compiler tells me that the reference "1sttablefoot" is undefined. Any ideas what could have gone wrong?

Comment: @Emiswelt That means you haven't placed `\label{1sttablefoot}` anywhere

Comment: Thank you for your reply. In fact, I have placed the label. The workaround for me, however, was to use \footnotetext[1]{\label{1sttablefoot}...} before the table and \footnotemark[\ref{1sttablefoot}] inside the table.

Comment: The given example can be improved by adding `\phantomsection` just before `\label`.

Comment: @SphericalTriangle that should not be necessary. Indeed IMHO it doesn't make much sense. What would be the purpose?

Comment: @clemens The purpose is to anchor the label at the right place otherwise a section which does NOT exit is looked for. On my box the \footref attached to F works well with this extra material.

Comment: @clemens This is a great answer, I had the same issue and this solved it. I was however, hoping to use numbers (1,2,3) instead of letters (a,b,c) in the superscript. Is there a way to achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: @user321627 yes: don't use the `minipage` environment. :)

Comment: It seems this solution does not work when the footnote is defined with captions.
Say I have `\footnote{\label{first} boogah boogah boogah}` in Caption for Table 1 and `\footref{first}` in Table 2. This causes a) the footnote to totally disappear and b) `??` in footnote for Table 2.

Comment: @Rakshit search this site for footnotes and captions and you'll soon find out that they're not a good combination

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply use `\textsuperscript{\ref{...}}` instead?

Comment: I suppose that won't work with `hyperref`?

Comment: @ThomasAhle: It works for me with hyperref.

Comment: Works for me to, inside a table. The red square around the footnote signaling the hyperlink is too small compared by the one given by \footnote, but this solution is simple and elegant