# footnote in multiple places in a table

Tags: tables

I want to add the same footnote in multiple places in a table. Can anyone please help me to do that.

```
 \befin{minipage}[b]{0.9\linewidth}
 \begin{tabular}{l l l }
 \hline
 a & b & c \footnote{this is the ref} \\
 d & f & e \footnote{I want the same foot note here}\\
 j & l & m \\
\end{tabular} 
\end{minipage}
```

Comment: What about [Multiple references to the same footnote inside a `table` environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/95866/5764)?

Comment: How about `\footnotemark[num]` for the repeats?

Comment: Do you want the footnote to appear at the bottom of the table (and numbered independently from other footnotes) or at the bottom of the page, with other footnotes?

Answer (score 4):

The `threeparttable` environment, provided by the [threeparttable](http://ctan.org/pkg/threeparttable) package, is designed to handle just this task.

The three parts of the `threeparttable` environment are (a) the caption, (b) the `tabular` (or `tabular*`, `tabularx`, or whatever) sub-environment, and (c) the `tablenotes` sub-environment. As the package's user guide says, there's nothing automatic about the table notes: You choose *how* they're labeled -- you can freely mix and match numbers, letters, and symbols should you want to do so -- and the *order* in which they should be placed. Footnote markers are generated with `\tnote{...}` directives in the `tabular(*xy)` environment, and the corresponding footnotes are placed after `\item [...]` statements in the `tablenotes` part of the structure.

In the example below I've chosen alphabetic labels. Do note that a `threeparttable` environment doesn't float (in the LaTeX sense of the word "float"). If you need it to float, encase it in a `table` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\renewcommand\TPTminimum{3in} 
\caption{A table with one repeated footnote}
\begin{tabular*}{3in}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ll} % select your preferred table environment here
\hline
 a & b & c\tnote{a} \\
 d & f & e\tnote{a}\\
 j & l\tnote{b} & m\\
\hline
\end{tabular*} 
\begin{tablenotes}
\item [a] The footnote that goes with marker ``a''
\item [b] The footnote that goes with marker ``b''
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use the package `scrextend` and its command `\footref{<key>}` where `<key>` is defined in a `\label{<key>}` into the ***footnote*** that you wish to repeat.

Here my code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.9\linewidth}
 \begin{tabular}{lll}
 \hline
 a\footnote{This is other note.} & b & c \footnote{\label{mynote}This is the repeated \textbf{ref}.} \\
 d & f & e \footref{mynote} \\%{I want the same foot note here}
 j & l & m \\
\end{tabular} 
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

And the result

[image]