# multiple reference to single footnotes in table

Tags: tables, cross-referencing

I have been trying to include multiple footnotes in a table. I have tried using longtable inside a minipage with \footnotes, \footnotemark and \footnotetext. I have multiple footnotes and some are referenced multiple times.

When using \footnotes, i am unable to make reference to an existing footnote using \footref.
I tried the solution here: [Multiple references to the same footnote inside a table environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95866/multiple-references-to-the-same-footnote-inside-a-table-environment), but i didn't have the scrextend or hyperref packages. I downloaded them and got some errors related to additional packages that i don't have. I'd rather not go chasing packages down the rabbit hole.

I also tried using foonotemark and footnotetext. Here, i am able to reference an existing footnote, but the footnote mark does not equate to the footnote mark with the text. i.e. the footnote mark will be 1, where as the text will have an 'a' next to it.

A block of latex that shows the second case.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,11pt]{report}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage[footnotesize,it,centerlast]{caption}
\usepackage[margin=3cm,includehead,heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[german,polish,danish,english]{babel}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text  text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.

\begin{minipage}{14cm}

\footnotesize
\begin{longtable}{ccccccc}
\caption{\normalsize{NGC 6791 measured asteroseismic properties}} \\
\hline

Target ID  \footnotemark[1] & Target ID  & $\nu_{max}$ ($\mu$Hz) & $\Delta\nu$ ($\mu$Hz) & Membership  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Seismic Membership}\\
KIC &  \scriptsize{(Stetson)}\footnotemark[2] & & & \scriptsize{(Platais)}\footnotemark[3]  \% & (Stello) \footnotemark[4] & This work      \\ 
\hline
\hline

    2297384 & 5583      & 30.4109   $\pm$ 1.303     & 0 \footnotemark[5]                    $\pm$ 0             & 93    & Yes           & Yes           \\
    2297574 & 8144      & 199.784   $\pm$ 0.019     & 1.4147        $\pm$ 0.0565    & 98    & -                 & Yes           \\
    2297793 & 11539     & 4.10564   $\pm$ 0.177     & 13.02769  $\pm$ 0.0230    & 0         & No            & No            \\
    2297825 & 11957     & 31.2304   $\pm$ 1.217     & 0.9261        $\pm$ 0.0714    & 94    & Yes           & Yes           \\
    2298097 & 14798     & 350.763   $\pm$ 0         & 8.90033       $\pm$ 0.0138    & 96    & -                 & No            \\
    2436291 & 2109      & 367.093   $\pm$ 0.945     & 5.18797       $\pm$ 0.0117    & 99    & -                 & No            \\
    2436543 & 3369      & 26.2462   $\pm$ 0.843 & 1.81895       $\pm$ 0.0106    & 99    & Unknown   & Yes           \\
\hline

\label{tab:NGC6791 measurements}
\end{longtable}


\begin{longtable}{cccccccc}

\caption{\normalsize{NGC 6819 measured asteroseismic properties}} \\
\hline

Target ID \footnotemark[1] & Target ID  & $\nu_{max}$ ($\mu$Hz) & $\Delta\nu$ ($\mu$Hz) & \multicolumn{2}{c}{RV Membership} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Seismic Membership}\\
KIC &  \scriptsize{(Hole)}\footnotemark[6] & &  & \scriptsize{(Hole)}\footnotemark[7] \% & \scriptsize{(Platais)}\footnotemark[3]  \% & (Stello) \footnotemark[4] & This work   \\ 
\hline   

    4937011     & 007017    & 27.731    $\pm$ 0.7867    & 4.0957    $\pm$ 0.0446    & 95        & 0         & no            & No        \\
    4937056     & 002012    & 45.600    $\pm$ 1.3478    & 4.7712    $\pm$ 0.0323    & 95        & 98    & yes           & Yes           \\
    4937140     & 012023    & 9.1849    $\pm$ 0.1366    & -7.9273   $\pm$ 1.2744    & 95        & 29    & 0             & No        \\
    4937770     & 009024    & 63.8529   $\pm$ 0.2095    & 7.8517        $\pm$ 0.0050    & 94        & 5         & yes           & maybe     \\
    5023863     &                   & 35.6772   $\pm$ 18.533    & 6.1099    $\pm$ 0.0421    &               &           & 0             & No        \\
    5023889     & 004014    & 53.5692   $\pm$ 0.5341    & 5.3712    $\pm$ 0.0133    & 95        & 0         & no            & No        \\
    5023890     & 009009    & 1.1005    $\pm$ 0.0297    & 0.2528    $\pm$ 0.0777    & 94        & 0         & 0             & No        \\
    5024582     & 009002    & 45.5678  $\pm$ 1.0244     & 4.7783    $\pm$ 0.0446    & BLM   & 99    & yes           & Yes           \\
\hline
\label{tab:NGC6819 measurements}
\end{longtable}

\footnotetext[1]{Only targets for which oscillations were detected are listed.} 
\footnotetext[2]{ID's from Stetson2003}
\footnotetext[3]{Membership probability from radial velocity Platais2011}
\footnotetext[4]{Seismic membership from Stello2011a}
\footnotetext[5]{SYD pipeline was unable to extract a value.}
\footnotetext[6]{ID's from Hole2009}
\footnotetext[7]{Membership probability from radial velocity Hole2009; BLM: binary likely member.}

\normalsize
\end{minipage}
\newline



text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot of results]

The alphanumeric characters should be 1 through to 7, or the footnote marks should be the corresponding alphanumeric characters.

Is there a solution for either of these options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using multiple `longtable` environments inside one and the same `minipage`, I would use a `table` environment as well as a `threeparttable` environment. Use `\tnote{...}` in the body of the `tabular`s to insert footnote markers, and use the `tablenotes` environment after the `tabular`s to list the footnotes using `\item` directives.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,11pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage[footnotesize,it,centerlast]{caption}
\usepackage[margin=3cm,includehead,heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage[german,polish,danish,english]{babel}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\footnotesize
\begin{threeparttable}

\caption{NGC 6791 measured asteroseismic properties}
\label{tab:NGC6791 measurements}

\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}ccccccc@{}}
\hline
Target ID\tnote{1} & Target ID  & $\nu_{max}$ ($\mu$Hz) & $\Delta\nu$ ($\mu$Hz) & Membership  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Seismic Membership}\\
KIC &  \scriptsize{(Stetson)}\tnote{2} & & & \scriptsize{(Platais)}\tnote{3}  \% & (Stello) \tnote{4} & This work      \\ 
\hline\hline
    2297384 & 5583      & 30.4109   $\pm$ 1.303     & 0 \tnote{5}                    $\pm$ 0             & 93    & Yes           & Yes           \\
    2297574 & 8144      & 199.784   $\pm$ 0.019     & 1.4147        $\pm$ 0.0565    & 98    & -                 & Yes           \\
    2297793 & 11539     & 4.10564   $\pm$ 0.177     & 13.02769  $\pm$ 0.0230    & 0         & No            & No            \\
    2297825 & 11957     & 31.2304   $\pm$ 1.217     & 0.9261        $\pm$ 0.0714    & 94    & Yes           & Yes           \\
    2298097 & 14798     & 350.763   $\pm$ 0         & 8.90033       $\pm$ 0.0138    & 96    & -                 & No            \\
    2436291 & 2109      & 367.093   $\pm$ 0.945     & 5.18797       $\pm$ 0.0117    & 99    & -                 & No            \\
    2436543 & 3369      & 26.2462   $\pm$ 0.843 & 1.81895       $\pm$ 0.0106    & 99    & Unknown   & Yes           \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tablenotes}
\item[1] Only targets for which oscillations were detected are listed. 
\item[2] ID's from Stetson2003
\item[3] Membership probability from radial velocity Platais2011
\item[4] Seismic membership from Stello2011a
\item[5] SYD pipeline was unable to extract a value.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Mico, that's a great solution, but i wanted something that would work for two separate tables, using one list of footnotes. You should be able to see this from the image. I will be able to use this solution for some of my other tables though, so thanks.

Comment: @theotheraussie - It's perfectly legal to have several `tabular` environments, each with its own `\caption`, inside a `threeparttable` environment.