# Multiple Footnotes in the same caption/figure/table/equation and using hyperref

Tags: pdftex

In need multiple footnotes in the caption of figures and tables and in `tabular` environments together with the package `hyperref`.

```
%LaTeX=>PDF
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
\caption[123]{A\footnote{\label{first}some footnote}B\tablefootnote{4}
X\footnotemark{} Y\footnotemark{} Z\footnotemark{}}
\end{figure}
 \addtocounter{footnote}{-3} %3=n
 \stepcounter{footnote}\footnotetext{a}
 \stepcounter{footnote}\footnotetext{b}
 \stepcounter{footnote}\footnotetext{c}
\end{document}
```

I get two different warnings:

```
pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{Hfootnote. }) has been already used, duplicate ignored
```

and

```
pdfTeX warning (dest): name{Hfootnote. } has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one
```

[image: result]

I tried

- [Using \footnote in a figure's \caption](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10181/using-footnote-in-a-figures-caption),
- [Warning with footnotes: "name{Hfootnote.xx} has been referenced but does not exist"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16268/warning-with-footnotes-namehfootnote-xx-has-been-referenced-but-does-not-exia),
- [\footnotetext numbering for many \footnotemark - automatic solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43692/footnotetext-numbering-for-many-footnotemark-automatic-solution),
- [Multiple references to the same footnote inside a table environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95866/multiple-references-to-the-same-footnote-inside-a-table-environment),
- [Footnotes in tables?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1583/footnotes-in-tables),

and several others but my problem seems to be more complicated than those, because I need multiple footnotes in combination with `hyperref`.

===================================================

I tried

```
%LaTeX=>PDF
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}\caption[123 456]{123\footnotemark 456\footnotemark}
\end{figure}
\addtocounter{footnote}{-1}
\footnotetext{\href{https://tex.stackexchange.com/}{stackexchange}}
\stepcounter{footnote}\footnotetext{\href{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_talk:JoKalliauer}{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User\_talk:JoKalliauer}}
\end{document}
```

and

```
%LaTeX=>PDF
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}\caption[123 456]{123\tablefootnote{\href{https://tex.stackexchange.com/}{stackexchange}} 456\tablefootnote{34}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

but also those lead to the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Solution can be found in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/440559/110064 (by @jesseknight): basically use https://ctan.org/pkg/footnotehyper

```
\usepackage{footnotehyper}
```