# \url{} does not properly work in \item when URL ends with a "/"

Tags: pdftex, itemize, urls

I want to have a list of websites in a itemize-environment, but I need to use `\usepackage{url}` instead of `\usepackage{hyperref}`, because hyperref creates some problems in the document (see [Multiple Footnotes in the same caption/figure/table and using hyperref](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/324498/multiple-footnotes-in-the-same-caption-figurer-table-and-using-hyperref)). Some of them end with a "/" but the link gets substituted with "/•" then the URL does not work any more.

```
%LaTeX=>PDF
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{tablefootnote} % allows to use several \tablefootnote in table&tabular
\usepackage{url}           % enables \url

\begin{document}  

\begin{itemize}
\item \url{http://www.washingtonpost.com/}
\item \url{http://www.newyorktimes.com/}
\item \url{http://www.lemonde.fr/}
\item \url{http://www.guardian.co.uk/}
\item \url{http://www.spiegel.de/}
\item \url{http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Click on the links in the PDF and you will see the links are not work properly.

Comment: There are no links in the PDF here: the `url` package does not create them. _Some_ PDF viewers make links 'on the fly' by interpreting the text of the PDF, but this is outside of the control of the 'TeX end'.

Comment: The issue you raise in the other question is a warning, not an error: you should still be perfectly fine including URLs as hyperlinks.

Comment: @JosephWright: Thanks, it was a problem of [Sumatra-PDF-Viewer](http://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/). Other PDF Viewers linked it correctly ([Foxit Reader](https://www.foxitsoftware.com/), [Nitro Reader](https://www.gonitro.com/pdf-reader/download), [PDF-XChange Editor](http://www.tracker-software.com/product/downloads/enduser/pdf-xchange-editor)), there are also PDF-Viewer which doesn't link \url{} using "\usepackage{url}" at all.
As you correctly said the url package does not create links, only some PDF-Viewers.

Comment: If you have problems with footnotes and `hyperref`, then disable the footnote support of `hyperef`: `hyperfootnotes=false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @JosephWright correctly said the `url` package does not create links, only some PDF-Viewers.
It was a problem of [Sumatra-PDF-Viewer](http://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/). Other PDF Viewers linked it correctly ([Foxit Reader](https://www.foxitsoftware.com/), [Nitro Reader](https://www.gonitro.com/pdf-reader/download), [PDF-XChange Editor](http://www.tracker-software.com/product/downloads/enduser/pdf-xchange-editor)), there are also PDF-Viewer which doesn't link `\url{}` using `\usepackage{url}` at all.