# Refer to the same footnote for many places in tabu

Tags: tables, footnotes, tabu

I tried to refer the same footnote for many places in the tabu and use this one as a reference, [Multiple references to the same footnote inside a table environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95866/multiple-references-to-the-same-footnote-inside-a-table-environment).

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tabu}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[t]
\caption{Input parameters}
\tabulinesep=1.2mm
\begin{tabu} to\linewidth {|X[2l] X[2l]|}
\hline 
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Test} \\ 
A & B \footnote{\label{first}first footnote}\\ 
C & D \footref{first}\\
\hline 
\end{tabu}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I get the result as in picture without any footnote at the bottom of the page.

[image: Error1]

However, if I use the code like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tabu}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabu} to\linewidth {|X[2l] X[2l]|}
\hline 
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Test} \\ 
A & B \footnote{\label{first}first footnote}\\ 
C & D \footref{first}\\
\hline 
\end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

I get no problem (with footnote at the bottom of the page).

[image: Without Error]

I've also tried `cleveref` already but I got ??.

Anything wrong with my first code?

Comment: footnotes in floats (like `table` and `figure`) disappear. You can split them up in a `\footnotemark` (inside the float) and `\footnotetext` (outside the float) but then you risk the float being moved to a different page than the footnote text.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion already and get the problem as you mentioned. So, I use `tablenote` from `\usepackage{threeparttable}` instead.