# Referring multiple times to the same footnote inside a cell of a floating table, using Lyx

Tags: lyx

Hi I basically followed the answers from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95866/multiple-references-to-the-same-footnote-inside-a-table-environment), but it turns out that the labelling basically woks, except for the referring to the same footnote. An "Table" is always set in front of the reference.
I have a float table, where I want to place some referring footnotes to the same footnote. As I am working with Lyx, I have problems to generate here an mini working example, but basically, I did the same as in the link above. I attached a screen shot of the Lyx evironement.

[image: Example table] [image: Screenshot of the Lyx Table].

I guess it trys to refer to the "Table a" footnote... but I have no idea how to get rid of this... I hope someone can help here. It is wired that no one else ran into this problem. At least I did not find any post on that topic.

Comment: Normally, \footnote uses \stepcounter instead of \refstepcounter.  Hyperref redefines \footnotemark and \footnotetext, not to mention defining \footref, so try that.

Comment: The problem is (if I understand it correct) that I need to place the \footnotemark behind the word (in this case '100pM') and the \footnotetext defines the footnote. The problem: How should I do this with multiple footnotes within one table? I cannot really order them, since the \footnotetext prints the footnote corresponding to the previous \footnotemark.

Comment: Okay, for reasons I do not know, the example above works like it should, without the word "table" appearing. The only thing I changed, was the label "note1". This should not influence the outcome... but anyway, it works for now.

Comment: If you were using note1 in another \label, LaTeX could get confused.  Without a MWE to test, this is all speculation.

Comment: Mhhh yeah, might be. As I am using Lyx, Lyx might use some labels like "note1" without knowing me... but I guess something like that must be the reason behind this "magic" that it is working now. Anyway, thanks for your help! :)

Comment: To add the minimal example, open the `.lyx` file in Notepad or some other text editor, and copy-paste the entire content into your question. After pasting, select the code and hit Ctrl + K.