# Let two things refer to the same footnote

Tags: footnotes, endnotes

I'm using footnotes (with the `endnote` package) to add references to my CV:

```
\let\footnote=\endnote
Jalv2\footnote{http://justanotherlanguage.org}
```

Now, I have two times the text "Jalv2" on my CV, and both times I want to refer to the same footnote. So like:

```
Jalv2\footnote{http://justanotherlanguage.org}
...
Jalv2\footnote{http://justanotherlanguage.org}
```

But this creates of course two footnotes while I only want one. How do I do that?

Comment: Maybe this is helpful: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10102/multiple-references-to-the-same-footnote-with-hyperref-support-is-there-a-bett

Comment: That's exactly what I need. Now uhm, close this as a duplicate? Or should I remove it?