# footnotes referencing previous footnotes BUT using parnotes package

Tags: footnotes

I tried all but one of the 6 examples (adapting/hacking it to see if I could get it to work with parnotes) in the question:

[Multiple references to the same footnote with hyperref support - is there a better solution?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10102/multiple-references-to-the-same-footnote-with-hyperref-support-is-there-a-bett/10116#10116)

and now I feel I need to ask. I use the amsart/lualatex combo, and here is a MWE.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[narrower,notessf]{parnotes}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\crefformat{footnote}{#2\footnotemark[#1]#3}

\begin{document}

\part{one}

\section{section1}
My paltry MWE \footnote{\label{one}I was not thinking but these last few words are now labeled `one'}.

\section{section2}

The above footnote containing my poor reason, while being true, can be referenced in the text, \cref{one}, or\footnote{in another footnote! By the way, see \cref{one}}.



\part{two}

\section{section3}

I would like to do the same as in the first part \parnote{So this parnote will be what I want to reference later on.\label{nine}}. I would like to do the same as in the first part. I would like to do the same as in the first part.

Wished this worked, referencing in the text produces the section number though - \cref{nine}...\parnote{Trying to reference in another parnote also doesn't work - \cref{nine} - it again just references the section...}
\parnotes

\end{document}
```

I think this pretty much explains my question I hope.

Comment: Maybe *you* don't need an MWE, but maybe people interested in working on this problem would find it easier if you gave them one.  It is, e.g., not entirely clear what you want.  Will parnotes refer to regular footnotes? only(?) to other parnotes? or footnotes to parnotes? Are your parnotes numbers resetting after each paragraph, or are they continuously numbered?  Does the linked question imply that `hyperref` must be part of the solution?  A well construted MWE would often implicitly or explicitly answer such questions.

Comment: I don't use `cleveref` myself. However, can it cope with plain TeX counters rather than LaTeX ones? `parnote` seems not to use LaTeX counters as far as I can tell. All the definitions are lower level.

Comment: **If** I understand correctly ;) I would say yes. My document is not that long and in particular this foot/par-note need not have any fancy bells and whistles...