# Multiple references to same footnotes in memoir with cleveref and french babel

Tags: footnotes, memoir, cleveref, report

I'm trying to have multiple references to a footnotes, in a class `memoir` (or report) and using `[french]babel` and `cleveref`.

According to this question [Multiple references to the same footnote with hyperref support - is there a better solution?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10102/multiple-references-to-the-same-footnote-with-hyperref-support-is-there-a-bett/10116?noredirect=1#comment689671_10116), I came up with minimal non working example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\crefformat{footnote}{#2\footnotemark[#1]#3}

\begin{document}
\section{foo}
First page, referencing future footnote\cref{second}.

Second paragraph, first footnote\footnote{\label{first}First footnote!}

\pagebreak
\section{bar}
Second page, creating the second footnote\footnote{\label{second}Second footnote}, 
and referencing the first footnote\cref{first}.
\end{document}
```

And I get :

[image: footnote reference wrong]

As you can see, the reference text is wrong (but the link is ok !). If I replace memoir with article, everything is fine, but report fails also.
What can be going on?

Thanks

Comment: Use `\frenchbsetup{FrenchFootnotes=false}` in the preamble.

Comment: thanks, that did the trick ! Can i ask where did you find that ?

Comment: Since the issue appears only with French, I looked in `frenchb.ldf` and indeed it monkeys with footnotes; this is apparently not at all liked by `memoir`. Happily, there's a way for disabling the changes. ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The French module for `babel` does some changes to the footnote management and, apparently, this breaks the cooperation between `memoir`, `hyperref` and `cleveref`.

Add

```
\frenchbsetup{FrenchFootnotes=false}
```

to your document preamble in order to disable those changes.

Comment: I may add this is also useful  for `report` class