# Cross reference footnote in a table

Tags: tables, footnotes

I need to use the same footnote number in more than one sentence. I looked at previous posts and found a similar question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10102/multiple-references-to-the-same-footnote-with-hyperref-support-is-there-a-bett/10116#10116). I applied the simplest solution that suggests adding a label to the footnote then use the label in a `\ref` in a `\textsuperscript` and use normal font by adding `\normalfont` after `\textsuperscript`.

The problems are:

1. The first footnote ttext does not appear at the button of the page. I just see the number on top of the sentence.
2. The second footnote does not appear at all neither the number nor the text. I want a simple solution that avoids adding new packages and commands as much as possible. But it is ok if there is not any other solution. I just see some horrible complication for how things are done in some posts and want to avoid that.

The first footnote:

```
Text1\footnote{\label{note1}footnote}
```

The second:

```
Text2\textsuperscript\normalfont{\ref{note1}}
```

The full script:

```
%README: this copy with comprehensive attack and defences description.

\documentclass[compsoc, conference, letterpaper, 10pt, times]{IEEEtran}
\ifCLASSOPTIONcompsoc
  % IEEE Computer Society needs nocompress option
  % requires cite.sty v4.0 or later (November 2003)
  \usepackage[nocompress]{cite}
\else
  % normal IEEE

  \usepackage{cite}
\fi
\ifCLASSINFOpdf
\else
\fi

\usepackage{colortbl}       
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

    % The new commands
    \newcommand{\midsepremove}{\aboverulesep = 0mm \belowrulesep = 0mm}
    \midsepremove
    \newcommand{\midsepdefault}{\aboverulesep = 0.605mm \belowrulesep = 0.984mm}
    \midsepdefault

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{justification=centering}

\usepackage{multirow}
\newcommand{\head}[1]{\textnormal{\textbf{#1}}}
\newcommand{\normal}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{l}{#1}}
\usepackage{amssymb}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amssymb
\usepackage{pifont}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pifont
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}%
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}%
\newcommand*\rot{\rotatebox{90}}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{msc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\quotes}[1]{``#1''} %for qoutation marks

\DeclareRobustCommand*{\IEEEauthorrefmark}[1]{%
\raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]{\textsuperscript{\footnotesize\ensuremath{#1}}}}

\begin{document}
\title{Test}

\maketitle

\begin{table}
\caption{mytable}
\label{table:mytable}
\centering

\midsepremove
\begin{tabular}{ l *{45}{c} }

  \toprule
    &   \multicolumn{3}{c}{B} \\
  \cmidrule(lr){2-4}
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{-2}{*}[0.5ex]{A}}
    &   AAA & BBB & CCC \\
  \midrule
  \rowcolor[gray]{.9}
  Text1\footnote{\label{note1}footnote} &   \cmark & \cmark & \cmark \\
  Text2\textsuperscript\normalfont{\ref{note1}} &   \xmark & \cmark & \xmark \\
  \rowcolor[gray]{.9}
  Text3 &   \cmark & \xmark & \xmark \\
  Text4 &   \cmark & \cmark & \cmark \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\midsepdefault

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: See also [Footnote in tabular environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109467/footnote-in-tabular-environment).